# how to change default font size for graphviz?

Tags: doxygen, graphviz

I use doxygen + graphviz for documenting my code. graphviz does a nice job of generating images.

Is there any way to change the default fontsize for graphviz? The default is 14, but I want to use 12 instead.

Its a real pain to change the fontsize for individual elements like, nodes, subgraphs, edges ... etc.

UPDATE:

For reference here is the code I'm using in doxygen, (the text fields have been renamed, of course)

```
@dot
 strict digraph {
   node [shape = box, fontsize = 12];
     subgraph cluster_main {
       fontsize = 12;
       shape    = box;
       label    = "main";
       subgraph cluster_main_common {
         fontsize = 12;
         shape    = box;
         label    = "common";
         subgraph cluster_main_common_source {
           fontsize = 12;
           shape    = box;
           label    = "source"
           subgraph cluster_file1 {
             fontsize = 12;
             shape    = box;
             label    = "file1.c";
             gSystem [label = "var1" URL = "\ref var1"];
           }
           subgraph cluster_file2 {
             fontsize = 12;
             shape    = box;
             label    = "file2.c";
             gCard [label = "var2" URL = "\ref var2"];
           }
           subgraph cluster_file3 {
             fontsize = 12;
             shape    = box;
             label    = "file3.c";
             gPwrSupply [label = "var3" URL = "\ref var3"];
           }
         }
       }
       subgraph cluster_main_docs {
         fontsize = 12;
         shape    = box;
         label    = "docs";
         subgraph cluster_main_docs_features {
           fontsize = 12;
           shape    = box;
           label    = "features";
           subgraph cluster_main_docs_features_source {
             fontsize = 12;
             shape    = box;
             label    = "source"
             subgraph cluster_file4 {
               fontsize = 12;
               shape    = box;
               label    = "file4.c";
               deviceInfo [label = "var4" URL = "\ref var4"];
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   @enddot
```

Comment: Useful question and answer below +1 to both!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Fontsize is a graph attribute (as well as an edge and node attribute). Doxygen generates a dot file, so, e.g.,:

```
strict digraph {
                 graph [ bgcolor=lightgray, resolution=128, fontname=Arial, fontcolor=blue, 
                         fontsize=12 ];
                 node [ fontname=Arial, fontcolor=blue, fontsize=11];
                 edge [ fontname=Helvetica, fontcolor=red, fontsize=10 ];

                }
```

Specific settings will override generic ones; hence setting fontsize as a node attribute will override the fontsize set as a graph attribute (just for nodes though), and setting fontsize for specific nodes will override fontsize set for all nodes.

If you try what i have above and it does not seem to work, change the fontsize, search your entire dot file for 'fontsize' settings, remove them, and re-set fontsize as a node attribute.

Here is the complete graphviz [attribute list](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html).

Comment: It's been a while since I looked into this, and I think I gave up in the end. Nevertheless, your update looks workable and for lack of anything better I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: try putting double quotes around the font name?  This worked for me.

Comment: I was using `labelfontcolor` described on the graphviz page, with no luck. `fontcolor` works fine though, thanks.