# Graphviz: how to set 'default' arrow style? 

Tags: graphviz, dot

Consider this `dot` language code:

```
digraph graphname {
    subgraph clusterA {
        node [shape=plaintext,style=filled];
        1 -> 2 [arrowhead=normal,arrowtail=dot];
        2 -> 3 -> X2 -> 5;
        6;
        7;
        label = "A";
        color=blue
    }
}
```

In the above example, only the `1 -> 2` connection will have the `arrowhead=normal,arrowtail=dot` style applied; all the other arrows will be of the "default" style.

My question is - how do I set the arrow style (for the entire subgraph - or for the entire graph), without having to copy paste "`[arrowhead=normal,arrowtail=dot];`" next to each edge connection?

EDIT: Just for reference - the [answer from Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4514445/277826) didn't contain any code; I wrote that snippet and had it in this space here - for unknown reasons, a moderator cut it off from here and pasted it into Jesse's answer.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the *edge* attribute statement, as stated in the [DOT Language documentation](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/lang.html).

```
digraph graphname {
    subgraph clusterA {
        node [shape=plaintext,style=filled];
        edge [arrowhead=normal,arrowtail=dot];
        1 -> 2 ;
        2 -> 3 -> X2 -> 5;
        6;
        7;
        label = "A";
        color=blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the answer, @JesseW - accept for the reference :) Btw, I was just found [doxygen - how to change default font size for graphviz? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938200/how-to-change-default-font-size-for-graphviz) which also, pretty much, explains the same :)

Comment: Just a note: you can also do this on the command line (i.e., without modifying the DOT file) by adding a command line parameter like `-Earrowtail=dot`.  More generally `-E` is used to set default *edge* attributes, `-N` to set default *node* attributes and `-G` to set default *graph* attributes.

Answer (score 10):

Just like you did for nodes, but using `edge`, e.g. `edge[style=dashed]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer too, @Fabian Steeg - gave the accept to @JesseW cause of the link :) Cheers!